# Удалить подстроку в строке начиная с символа переноса

Tags: php, строки

У меня есть строка, в которой я хочу удалить все с момента двойного переноса строки \n\n
reply_message_text = 'Это надо оставить \n\n Это надо удалить'

```
strstr($reply_message_text, '\n\n', true)
```

Но это возвращает пустую строку, помогите разобраться пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего использовать функцию `explode()` с `'\n\n'` в качестве разделителя, и возвратить элемент массива с индексом 0.

```
$parts = explode('\n\n', $reply_message_text);
$result = $parts[0];
```

Или через `substr()` :

```
$pos = strpos($reply_message_text, '\n\n');
$result = substr($reply_message_text, 0, $pos);
```

Ещё можно взять `strstr()` с параметром `"before_needle"`:

```
$result = strstr($reply_message_text, '\n\n', true);
```

или так:

```
$parts = explode('\n\n', $reply_message_text);
$result = $parts[0];
```

Либо вырезать ту часть строки, которая идет до первого вхождения искомой подстроки:

```
$pos = strpos($reply_message_text, '\n\n');
$result = substr($reply_message_text, 0, $pos);
```

Если ни один из способов не работает, проверь наличие символов `'\n\n'` в строке.